# How to improve SELECT query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Is there a way to improve my query

```
SELECT *
FROM  StringControllerDaten
WHERE StringControllerDaten.Erstellt NOT IN
(
    SELECT  
            Min(Erstellt) AS Erstellt   
    FROM        StringControllerDaten

    GROUP BY
    StringControllerDaten.StringController,
    DATEPART(YEAR, Erstellt),
    DATEPART(MONTH, Erstellt),
    DATEPART(DAY, Erstellt),
    DATEPART(HOUR, Erstellt),
    (DATEPART(MINUTE, Erstellt) / 15)
)
```

This query returns all data who doesn't match one of the min Datetimes from the 15Min Interval.

It is running again +1Mio Row's and takes hours.

---

### Edit:

the estimated query plan

[image: estimated query plan]

Comment: Check and post the query plan

Comment: Definitely avoiding `select *` will help. It's better to put the column names explicitly than `*`.
Query plan will explain a lot and, more importantly, it will show the most time-consuming task within your query.

Comment: Use a table variable to store the `Min(Erstellt)` first and then use that table inside the NOT IN

Comment: Are your tables indexed properly? Could you attach `.sqlplan` file? Adding some sample data would help.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas where do i find this file?

Comment: Please see this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/aczno8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a list of dates with 15 min interval between min and max Erstellt put then in a table/cursor/temptable.

> See [Generate a resultset of incrementing dates in TSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1478951/generate-a-resultset-of-incrementing-dates-in-tsql)

Lets say the table looks like:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AllDates]
    ( COLUMN Item DATETIME)
```

2. Cross compare your table with list from 1.

   ```
   SELECT
      StringControllerDaten.ID -- or what you need
   FROM
      StringControllerDaten
   WHERE
      StringControllerDaten.Erstellt NOT IN (SELECT AllDates.Item FROM AllDates)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Could the top answer in this thread help you?

EDIT: still need to figure out how get the `NOT IN` into an Inner Join

[Complex join with nested group-by/having clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579175/complex-join-with-nested-group-by-having-clause)

achinda99 wrote: "In most database systems, the JOIN works a lost faster than doing a WHERE ... IN."

Got no means of testing atm, tho.